# Firebase App Indexing Android Search Result

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

I have implemented all the steps that are mentioned on this link: [Firebase App Indexing Start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app). All the test your implementation steps mentioned in above are working fine. My app is also searchable in Google App [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb2gq.png). I have cross checked back button violation , content mismatch as mentioned in google documentation. We have a live website with properly indexed pages,my app is in play store.My website can be found with google search result, if you tap the link it all ask to open via app,if opened in app it will redirect to that specific content. Yet the app icons which generally appear with indexed URLs along with  web links are not showing in search results. I am unable to identify the problem. Can some body explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: I didn't have much reputation to put more links for other images. Test your implmention link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test

Comment: if you mean in public search result then you need to wait.

Comment: Yes. Its almost 48 hours , how much time it takes?

Comment: try to search with maximum similarity to text of your website. you should see you website link in search result that connect to your app.

Comment: Web links are indexed already , my app icon is not showing in search result. If you taps the link it will asks to open via app and if you choose app then it is directing to that specific content.

Answer (score 0):

The Indexing in way you implemented is local. it means they are available only on a phone and not accessible through Internet.
first you need to have Website. then when search result from you website shown on Google and user click on your website link, Android System will ask user how to open it. inside target app or in Browser.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://recipe-app.com/recipe" -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="recipe-app.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://recipe-app.com/recipe" -->
        <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="recipe-app.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
    </intent-filter>
```

here website is www.recipe-app.com so if user see some result from this website on google search result then he can open it inside your app. and app should be published on google play store. hope it helps!

also i recommend to read this Codelab 
http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#1

Comment: I have running a website  , whose links are indexed properly, my app is updated in play store.

Comment: The link that you have mentioned I have already gone though it along with all you tube videos by google. Coding part is completely done.